# Spring MVC: <spring:bind> and two model attributes in one form

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, jsp

I have prepared a form to handle two models:

```
<form action="rentBook2" method="post">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <spring:bind path="book.id">
                       <input value="${book.id}" type="hidden" name="id"/><br />
                    </spring:bind>

                    <spring:bind path="client.id">
                       <input value="${client.id}" type="hidden" name="id"/><br />
                    </spring:bind>

                    <td><label>Rental Date:</label></td>
                    <td>            
                    <spring:bind path="book.rentalDate">
                       <input type="text" name="rentalDate"/><br />
                    </spring:bind>

                    <tr>
                    <td><label>Return Date:</label></td>
                    <td>
                    <spring:bind path="book.returnDate">
                       <input type="text" name="returnDate"/><br />
                    </spring:bind>
                    </td>

                    <tr><td></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>
```

For better understanding: book.id and client.id are hidden because this value is already passing by get method and request param in url from previus form.

But the problem is: I am able to receive book.id, book.rentalDate and book.returnDate from book input. What is wired, client.id has the same value as book.id (what is of course incorrect).

This is my controller method:

```
@PostMapping("/rentBook2")
public String rentBook2(@ModelAttribute("book") Book theBook, @ModelAttribute("client") Client theClient) {

    System.out.println("This is book in controller : " + theBook);
    System.out.println("This is client in controller : " + theClient);

    bookService.rentBook(theBook.getId(), theClient.getId());
    bookService.saveBook(theBook);

    return "redirect:/book/list-books";
}
```

And the example output from println:

```
This is book in controller : Book [id=19, title=null, author=null, genre=null, rentalDate=20-02-2019, returnDate=25-02-2019, client=null]
This is client in controller : Client [id=19, firstName=null, lastName=null, email=null]
```

The value "19" which you can see above is from ${book.id} but the correct one for ${client.id} should be "6".

Have you any idea why the book.id and client.id have the same value?

Comment: That isn't weird it is as expected. The input fields have the same name, this results in an array being posted (something like `id=19&id=6` in the body). And when binding only the first value will be used.

Comment: @M.Deinum, so shall I change the name on spring entity level? To more unique?

Answer (score 0):

As advised by @M. Deinum, the problem was in not enough unique field names. I have changed from id to idBook and from id to idClient and the mechanism is working as expected.

Thanks @M. Deinum!

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to add transient variables to any of your classes so you can handle every value via one model attribute (one object of your desired class) and then do all the logic with that object.

Comment: Also note that you're retrieving your book.id and your client.**id** and they will map the same value since they have the same name. For better context, try retrieving another attribute of your class (for example book.name) and you won't face the problem again but this is not a good solution in my opinion.